# Java EE Web Security

Tags: java, xml, maven, security, tomcat

I have a login page (`welcome-page.jsp`) which checks if the user exists in a database. If the password that he has provided is correct and if the type is correct, he is redirected on a page. Now I want to add some security in sending data. I'm new to this ...
Here is the login form

```
<form method="POST" action="authentification">
        USERNAME: <input type="text" name="username" />
        PASSWORD: <input type="password" name="password" /><br/><br/>
        LOG AS:
            <select name="type">
                <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
            </select>
        <input type="submit"value="Login"/>
    </form>
```

and here is the web.xml (as far as I understood here's the place to add security to sending data from forms). Is it possible to add security without creating tomcat users and user-roles? I'm using tomcat 7

```
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>/welcome-page.jsp</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/authentification</url-pattern>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>

<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

```
   <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/welcome-page.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/authentification-failed.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

Comment: Hey what kind of security you want  application level or  tomcat level.

Comment: I would like to have request from login page sent to filter and servlet in a securized way

Comment: Walk through this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bncby/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat can be configured to use (username/password or SSL client certificate) authentication and only role-based authorization. So if you want different roles, then yes, you will have to create roles. If you are only using a single role for all users, then you can use the "*" role.

What you are missing in your `web.xml` are `<security-constraint>` elements. Have a look at the servlet spec documentation for how to write a security-constraint.

Comment: thank you but actually my question was if it is possible to make a secure transfer of data without tomcat SSL client certificate. if i write every username, password and role in xml file, my project won't be too dynamic i think. i want to take them from a database but to make sure that data is secured when transmited. i'm not sure if i described it well enough

Comment: I'm still not clear... secure communication is separate from authentication (though secure communication should *always* be used for authentication). If you just want to authenticate against a database, then you want to use something like `DateSourceRealm` and not `MemoryRealm` (which is the realm that uses `tomcat-users.xml` by default). With `DataSourceRealm`, you can authenticate *and* authorize against users and roles stored in a data source accessible via a JDBC DataSource.